# Only allow commands to be run if a setup one has been completed in Commander.js

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, argv, node-commander

Is it possible in commander.js to check that a `setup` command has been run and completed before allowing any other actions to be run.

If a command is attempted to be run it will show a message to run the `$ command auth` first

Comment: If this is a state in your program, spread across several invocations, you need to save this yourself. What steps do you do in your `setup` command?

Comment: I am currently saving the completed state using configstore, but I would like to check in each command that this setup command has been completed successfully so far even when I call the checkSetup() function in my actions and return the rest of the action still runs after

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to easily do that in commander.js. You need to do that on each commands `.action`, or you could do it when you setup the commander.

```
program
  .command('setup')
  .action(function () {
    console.log('setup done');
    storeSetup();
  });

if (setupHasRun()) {
  program
    .command('ls [dirs...]')
    .action(function (dirs) {
        console.log('ls %s', dirs);
    });

  program 
    .command('rmdir <dir> [otherDirs...]')
    .action(function (dir, otherDirs) {
      console.log('rmdir %s', dir);
      if (otherDirs) {
        otherDirs.forEach(function (oDir) {
          console.log('rmdir %s', oDir);
        });
      }
    });  
}
```